# Send email to a list of addresses in Google Scripts

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I have a list of orders on one sheet, and I have a list of emails on another sheet. The emails are one per cell, starting in Column K3 in my sheet, to be updated manually as emails get added and removed.

I want my script to send an email notification to all the emails on the list, but I am getting an error when it comes to the MailApp function. I have the code below and an example sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Imw5eQ964zC0IPUjz5V7KqiJgnzC18niCLSs8kkXIw/edit#gid=1443162644).

```
function RDCsendEmail() {
var RawMaterialSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Order List");[enter link description here][1]

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var response = ui.prompt('Set Row Number for RM Received', 'Enter ROW #, from left side of sheet, that matches RM Received', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

var RowNumber = response.getResponseText()


var Plant = RawMaterialSheet.getRange('C'+ RowNumber).getValue(); 

var EnteredBy = RawMaterialSheet.getRange('B'+ RowNumber).getValue(); 

var HM_number = RawMaterialSheet.getRange('D'+ RowNumber).getValue(); 

var HM_Description = RawMaterialSheet.getRange('E'+ RowNumber).getValue(); 

var PurchaseOrder = RawMaterialSheet.getRange('F'+ RowNumber).getValue(); 

var PurchaseOrderQTY = RawMaterialSheet.getRange('H'+ RowNumber).getValue(); 

var PO_DUEDATE = RawMaterialSheet.getRange('I'+ RowNumber).getValue();
  
var Carrier = RawMaterialSheet.getRange('J'+ RowNumber).getValue(); 

var TrackingNumber = RawMaterialSheet.getRange('K'+ RowNumber).getValue(); 

var Reason = RawMaterialSheet.getRange('L'+ RowNumber).getValue(); 

var PComments = RawMaterialSheet.getRange('M'+ RowNumber).getValue(); 

var WHComments = RawMaterialSheet.getRange('N'+ RowNumber).getValue(); 


var Message= "Entered By:  " + EnteredBy +
  "\n\nPlant:  " + Plant +
  "\n\nMaterial Number:  " + HM_number +
  "\n\nMaterial Description:  " + HM_Description +
  "\n\nPurchase Order:  " + PurchaseOrder+
  "\n\nQuantity:  " + PurchaseOrderQTY + " KGs" +
  "\n\nPurchase Order Due Date:  " + PO_DUEDATE +
  "\n\nCarrier:  " + Carrier +
  "\n\nTracking Number:  " + TrackingNumber +
  "\n\nReason for HOT:  " + Reason +
  "\n\nComments from Planner:  " + PComments +
  "\n\nComments from WH:  " + WHComments +
  "\n\nLink: " + Link;   


var Sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Emails")
var lastRow = Sheet2.getLastRow();
var Range = Sheet2.getRange(3,11,lastRow, 1);
Logger.log("the range of emails is" + Range)
var EmailAddresses = Range.getValues();
var d = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i-d<EmailAddresses.length;i++) {
   if(!EmailAddresses[i-d][0]){
   EmailAddresses.splice(i-d, 1);
   d++; 
 }
Logger.log("the email addresses are" + EmailAddresses)
}

var Subject = "CA/DV RDC - HOT Material Arrived: PO " + PurchaseOrder + " for " + HM_number + " " + HM_Description;
MailApp.sendEmail(EmailAddresses.join(","), Subject, Message); 
MailApp.sendEmail(RawMaterialSheet.getRange('B' + RowNumber).getValue(), Subject, Message); // Sends email to the address listed in Column B
```

}

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]  Your code is incomplete and thus not reproducible.

Comment: You should always quote the exact text of the error. Try `MailApp.sendEmail(EmailAddresses.join(","), Subject, Message); 
`

Comment: @TheMaster - I tried that modification, did not work

Comment: @Cooper full code updated

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what you are trying to do with the list of emails perhaps you need to show us what your emails list looks like.  I omitted all that stuff you are doing with splice.  I also got all of your data with one read.

```
function RDCsendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rmsh = ss.getSheetByName("Order List");
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Set Row Number for RM Received', 'Enter ROW #, from left side of sheet, that matches RM Received', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    var row = Number(response.getResponseText());
    const [b,c,d,e,f,,h,ii,jj,k,l,m,n] = rmsh.getRange(`B${row}:N:${row}`).getValues();
    var Message = "Entered By:  " + b +
      "\n\nPlant:  " + c +
      "\n\nMaterial Number:  " + d +
      "\n\nMaterial Description:  " + e +
      "\n\nPurchase Order:  " + f +
      "\n\nQuantity:  " + h + " KGs" +
      "\n\nPurchase Order Due Date:  " + ii +
      "\n\nCarrier:  " + jj +
      "\n\nTracking Number:  " + k +
      "\n\nReason for HOT:  " + l +
      "\n\nComments from Planner:  " + m +
      "\n\nComments from WH:  " + n +
      "\n\nLink: " + Link;
    var esh = ss.getSheetByName("Emails")
    var emails = esh.getRange(3, 11, esh.getLastRow() - 2).getValues().flat();
    var Subject = "CA/DV RDC - HOT Material Arrived: PO " + f + " for " + d + " " + e;
    MailApp.sendEmail(emails.join(","), Subject, Message);
    MailApp.sendEmail(rmsh.getRange('B' + row).getValue(), Subject, Message);
  }
}
```